# How do Predators store their Combi-Stick?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

In the "Alien Vs Predator" series of movies, the Predators habitually carry a Combi-Stick on their backs.

**Could somebody please tell me what keeps the Predators' Combi-Stick in place on their backs?**

I'm aware that in the "AvP" **toy** the spear is held in place with a plastic clip but I'm fairly sure this is not what the Predators actually use!

Answer (score 3):

There's actually quite a nice shot of the combi-spear in *AVP1*;

[image: AVP1 Combi-Spear]

It appears to adhere to the Predator's armour magnetically, approximately halfway along its length.

Here it is from another angle. Again, there's no visible means of attachment which strongly suggests that it sticks on with [magnets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPblw.jpg).

[image: AVP1 Combi-Spear 2]

Comment: @Thecrazybull - Remind me, are you in the process of writing an extremely thorough fanfic about the Predator's dressing habits?

Comment: Haha no im one of those (weird) people who tend to ask questions about little things in games/movies that wonder about some things

Comment: That means ferrous metals. i.e. iron content.

Comment: @Omegacron - Yeah, but how do they work?